# how do you add html elements into an angular expression?

Tags: html, angularjs, expression

I have this in an HTML table:

```
<td><strong>{{item.title ? item.title : "<p style='color: grey'>select this item to edit</p>"}}</strong></td>
```

Unfortunately this does not have the effect that I thought it would.

It seems like the '<' bracket breaks the angular binding to the data.

I'm not sure how I should make this expression work.. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it differently

```
<td>
    <strong ng-show="item.title">{{item.title}}</strong>
    <strong ng-show="!item.title"><p style='color: grey'>select this item to edit</p></strong>

</td>
```

Something along those lines.  The angular way (at least to my understanding) isn't about manipulating and transforming strings into DOM elements.

Comment: this is simple and easy to implement versus using ngBindHtml.. i just tested and does the job.

Comment: sure I get that you can use it (ngBind).  I don't love it (ngBind), as the HTML generation is now relegated to a controller somewhere, and not with the rest of the HTML.

Comment: I should probably have described the problem in more detail so you could elaborate on your answer @akaphenom.. my apologies.

I have some nested controllers in my use case some of which are modal controllers, and I'm having to use a viewmodel data service i wrote to pass the objects cleanly between the scopes.

I'm still learning angular, but starting to get the hang of it, ... this just seemed like a very simple way around dealing with it.. for my use case atleast.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my comments - as they were not clear (i am rushing out), but at this point I should clarify.  I don't like the ngBind solution as it separates where the HTML is generated from the remainder of the HTML.  In the solution I provided the HTML remains in one place - and which HTML to display is controlled via a  flag.  It makes the HTML easier to maintain.   Note: there are other constructs like ng-if ng-switch that act similarly (HTML in one place)  through different features/implementations, but show should be fine here...

Answer (score 2):

use ngBindHtml

official guide: [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: I'll need to look at this more carefully.. it is probably the recommended way; however, I have a data model service in use and this particular area is presented via a modal controller.  I move the object around using the service so attaching objects to it in the modal scope may work for this.